# Adding GTM script to react component RendertoString

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Isomorphic React application to render the page. I have to add the GTM script to the page and when i add to java script file, babel fails due to the quotes and other things, may i know how i can escape or make sure babel skips this. It is failing in `redertoString` function

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using React's [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

like this

```
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
      new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
      'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
      })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');`
  }}
/>
```

Comment: let me give it a try

Comment: alhamdulellah :P